# <@USERID> Does not work in Discord Embeds v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to add to the `.setFooter()` of an embed a simple message such as `"This was developed by <@USERID>"`. However, this isn't working anymore but it used to work before. How do i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot place mentions inside a footer. Footers only accept basic strings. If you want to place a user's name or actual id use `<User>.username` or `<User>.id` with template strings.

Answer (score -1):

It's because USERID is not a thing, try this

```js
// in the beggining of your code
const DevId = "your id here"

// in your embed settings
.setFooter(`This bot was developed by <@${DevId}>`)
```

or

```js
// Beggining of the code
const DevId = `<@your id>`


// in your embed
.setFooter(`This bot was developed by ${DevId}`)
```

Comment: `USERID` was most likely a place holder for their id. The issue is that the OP is trying to mention inside of a footer.

Comment: No paramter or functionailty of `.setFooter()` shows a user's profile, only string and image parameters as shown in the documentation [Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor)

Comment: I already stated that doesn't work and i found out this doesn't work for footers. thanks for the help though